# Позиционирование с использованием position: absolute; и margin/padding

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Можно ли позиционировать объекты при верстке используя тег position: absolute; и применяя margin/padding?

Comment: нет, position absolute для другого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, только это будет совсем неудобно.

Пример с grid-сеткой:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  padding: 0 2vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4vw;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.node {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
  <div class="node"></div>
</div>
```

Тоже самое с абсолютным позиционированием:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.node {
  --p: 2vw;
  --h: 30vh;
  position: absolute;
  
  width: calc(100% / 4 - var(--p) * 2);
  height: var(--h);
  background-color: tomato;
}

.node-1 {
  left: var(--p);
}

.node-2 {
  left: calc(100% / 4 + var(--p));
}

.node-3 {
  left: calc(100% / 2 + var(--p));
}

.node-4 {
  left: calc(100% - 100% / 4 + var(--p));
}

@media (max-width: 477px) {
  .node {
    width: calc(100% / 3 - var(--p) * 2);
  }
  
  .node-1 {
    left: var(--p);
  }

  .node-2 {
    left: calc(100% / 3 + var(--p));
  }

  .node-3 {
    left: calc(100% - 100% / 3 + var(--p));
  }
  
  .node-4 {
    left: var(--p);
    top: calc(var(--h) + var(--p) * 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="node node-1"></div>
<div class="node node-2"></div>
<div class="node node-3"></div>
<div class="node node-4"></div>
```

и то я не до конца доделал, потому что это слишком утомительно.

---

Абсолютное позиционирование используется для того, чтобы не мешать остальным(основным) элементам спокойно себе существовать и радоваться жизни. Так, например, `position: absolute` очень часто используется для различных украшательств.

Красным кружочком обвёл элементы с абсолютным позиционированием
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

`margin` и `padding` применяется для того, чтобы расположить элемент так как нужно(хочется) уже внутри какой-то структуры... или подвинуть саму структуру

```js
ul_margin_input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  ul_margin_value.innerText = e.target.value
  setProperty('--um', e.target.value)
})

li_margin_input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  li_margin_value.innerText = e.target.value
  setProperty('--lm', e.target.value)
})

div_margin_input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  div_margin_value.innerText = e.target.value
  setProperty('--dm', e.target.value)
})

ul_padding_input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  ul_padding_value.innerText = e.target.value
  setProperty('--up', e.target.value)
})

li_padding_input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  li_padding_value.innerText = e.target.value
  setProperty('--lp', e.target.value)
})

div_padding_input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  div_padding_value.innerText = e.target.value
  setProperty('--dp', e.target.value)
})

function setProperty(p, v) {
  ul.style.setProperty(p, v + 'px')
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #6e5773;
  color: #e9e1cc;
}

ul {
  margin-left: var(--um);
  padding-left: var(--up);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #d45079;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: var(--lm);
  padding-left: var(--lp);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ea9085;
}

div {
  margin-left: var(--dm);
  padding-left: var(--dp);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: #e9e1cc;
  color: #6e5773;
}


/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

.inputs {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.inputs_1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.inputs_2 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.info>p {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.info>p>span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.info>p:nth-child(1)>span {
  background-color: #d45079;
}

.info>p:nth-child(2)>span {
  background-color: #ea9085;
}

.info>p:nth-child(3)>span {
  background-color: #e9e1cc;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul" style="--um: 0; --up: 0; --lm: 0; --lp: 0; --dm: 0; --dp: 0">
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<aside class="inputs inputs_1">
  <label>
    <p>ul margin: <span id="ul_margin_value">0</span></p>
    <input type="range" id="ul_margin_input" value="0">
  </label>
  <label>
    <p>li margin: <span id="li_margin_value">0</span></p>
    <input type="range" id="li_margin_input" value="0">
  </label>

  <label>
    <p>div margin: <span id="div_margin_value">0</span></p>
    <input type="range" id="div_margin_input" value="0">
  </label>
</aside>

<aside class="inputs inputs_2">
  <label>
    <p>ul padding: <span id="ul_padding_value">0</span></p>
    <input type="range" id="ul_padding_input" value="0">
  </label>

  <label>
    <p>li padding: <span id="li_padding_value">0</span></p>
    <input type="range" id="li_padding_input" value="0">
  </label>

  <label>
    <p>div padding: <span id="div_padding_value">0</span></p>
    <input type="range" id="div_padding_input" value="0">
  </label>
</aside>

<aside class="info">
  <p>ul: <span></span></p>
  <p>li: <span></span></p>
  <p>div: <span></span></p>
  <p>всё тоже самое применимо и к другим сторонам</p>
</aside>
```

Comment: надеюсь помог, потому что я сам с этим жутко страдал )

Answer (score 0):

Пример, для чего можно использовать `position: absolute`

```css
navedi {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

navedi::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

navedi:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<navedi>Наведи на меня</navedi>
```